# reopen a pipe in php for writing new commands to an executable

Tags: php, proc-open

I'm trying to send multiple commands (separated) to a program using php, I'm using /bin/bash for my test now and I'm facing a problem when I try to reopen the pipe to write the new command. here is the code , the commented part is the part where I tried reopening the pipe but with no luck it was commented because if I uncomment it the execution fails and I get a blank page.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a")
);
$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array();

$process = proc_open('/bin/bash', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
$cmds = array("whoami", "pwd");
#for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
if (is_resource($process)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $cmds[0]);
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

}

/*
        popen($pipes[0], 'w');
        fwrite($pipes[0], $cmds[1]);
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        popen($pipes[1], 'r')
        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
 */
proc_close($process);
```

Comment: Check if you have permissions to open the file

Comment: When you close the pipe, the other process gets EOF.  Reopening won't allow you to continue writing to it.

Comment: I was able to read the first command from the file so I think I have permission for that, however how can I check if I have permission to open the pipe that I created ?

Comment: `bash` exits when it gets EOF on its standard input.

Comment: @Barmar how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: BTW, these are unnamed pipes, not named pipes.

Comment: Don't close the pipe in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar how can I read from the other end if I don't close the writing end ? + I edited the question thanks

Comment: The problem is that `stream_get_contents()` reads until EOF, so it won't return until `bash` exits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239554/discussion-between-no-one-and-barmar).

Comment: I think you need to need to use the [`expect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.expect.php) library, not `proc_open()`.